# Azure Stream Analytics GetRecordPropertyValue puzzle

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

Could anyone please spot easily what am I doing wrong here?

I'm using the query below:

```
SELECT
    GetArrayElement(Requests.context.custom.dimensions, 0),
    GetType( GetArrayElement(Requests.context.custom.dimensions, 0)),
    GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(Requests.context.custom.dimensions, 0), "Response-Body")
INTO
    PowerBICreateScheduleDurations
FROM
    AppInsightsIncomingRequests AS Requests
```

To parse this input file:

{
    "request": [{
            "id": "dff22190-ecc8-44d2-aa3f-453c3d533c4d",
            "name": "",
            "count": 1,
            "responseCode": 401,
            "success": false,
            "url": "",
            "urlData": {
                "base": "",
                "host": "",
                "hashTag": "",
                "protocol": "https"
            },
            "durationMetric": {
                "value": 4786.0,
                "count": 1.0,
                "min": 4786.0,
                "max": 4786.0,
                "stdDev": 0.0,
                "sampledValue": 4786.0
            }
        }
    ],
    "internal": {
        "data": {
            "id": "f0b0f800-ab16-11e8-89c8-ed6412963258",
            "documentVersion": "1.61"
        }
    },
    "context": {
        "data": {
            "eventTime": "2018-08-28T23:05:54.8884157Z",
            "isSynthetic": false,
            "samplingRate": 100.0
        },
        "cloud": {},
        "device": {
            "type": "PC",
            "roleName": "",
            "roleInstance": "",
            "screenResolution": {}
        },
        "session": {
            "isFirst": false
        },
        "operation": {
            "id": "dff22190-ecc8-44d2-aa3f-453c3d533c4d",
            "parentId": "dff22190-ecc8-44d2-aa3f-453c3d533c4d",
            "name": ""
        },
        "location": {
            "clientip": "0.0.0.0",
            "continent": "North America",
            "country": "United States"
        },
        "custom": {
            "dimensions": [{
                    "Response-Body": "response 0"
                }, {
                    "Operation Name": ""
                }, {
                    "ApimanagementRegion": ""
                }, {
                    "ApimanagementServiceName": ""
                }, {
                    "Cache": "None"
                }, {
                    "API Name": ""
                }, {
                    "HTTP Method": "GET"
                }
            ],
            "metrics": [{
                    "Response Size": {
                        "count": 1.0,
                        "max": 343.0,
                        "min": 343.0,
                        "sampledValue": 343.0,
                        "stdDev": 0.0,
                        "sum": 343.0,
                        "value": 343.0
                    }
                }, {
                    "Request Size": {
                        "count": 1.0,
                        "max": 0.0,
                        "min": 0.0,
                        "sampledValue": 0.0,
                        "stdDev": 0.0,
                        "sum": 0.0,
                        "value": 0.0
                    }
                }, {
                    "Client Time (in ms)": {
                        "count": 1.0,
                        "max": 0.0,
                        "min": 0.0,
                        "sampledValue": 0.0,
                        "stdDev": 0.0,
                        "sum": 0.0,
                        "value": 0.0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

The desired behavior is for the `GetRecordPropertyValue...` line to extract the "response 0" string, yet it returns null.  The downloaded output is below:

```
[{
        "getarrayelement": {
            "Response-Body": "response 0"
        },
        "gettype": "record",
        "getrecordpropertyvalue": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change you query to use single quotes around 'Response-Body'. In SQL double quotes are used to escape column names (similar to []) so you query is interpreted as column with name "Response-Body" instead of string constant "Response-Body"

SELECT
    GetArrayElement(Requests.context.custom.dimensions, 0),
    GetType( GetArrayElement(Requests.context.custom.dimensions, 0)),
    GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(Requests.context.custom.dimensions, 0), 'Response-Body')
INTO
    PowerBICreateScheduleDurations
FROM
    AppInsightsIncomingRequests AS Requests

Comment: Fantastic, thanks very much!  Would it be possible for the query editor to highlight double quotes and offer as a tool tip the suggestion on when to use double/single quotes?  That's because not everyone who writes ASA queries has necessarily extensive SQL knowledge :-(